# Azure: A guide for an availability set for Virtual Machine with a Storage

Tags: azure, high-availability, bizspark

A goal of this post is to find out a guide on creating an availability set in Azure for a typical web-site running on a virtual machine with a storage connected to the virtual machine.

In best scenario, the guide should help developers running in Azure to reduce the downtime of the web-site in case of some temporary failure in networking/storage, etc while retaining the maintenance fees as low as possible.

The questions are:

1. Is it possible to have two virtual machines and storages within an availability set from different regions mostly synchronized and the guide to achieve that.
2. Is it possible to have one VM and storage asleep and woken up upon alarm of the network (or any 
   other) fail or the known issue received from Azure Support and the guide for that.
3. Any other questions that community may be faced to and being added here later.

Answer (score 3):

1. It's not possible to have an availability set span different regions as they are created inside the container of a cloud service. If you want to have high availability across different regions, you need to use the traffic manager which allows you to combine cloud services. This does however require you to deploy 2 separate cloud services and sync the data/storage in the back yourself.
2. Yes. You can put 1 (or more) VM to sleep and start them based on a triggered. You would need to use a 3rd party service like AzureWatch to setup a good trigger or build something yourself ,for example, via Azure Automation.